# how do i make my website accessible to the internet without a static ip and from a virtual machine?

Tags: networking, apache2, dns, webserver, router

I have windows 8 host and i have installed ubuntu 14.10 server as a virtual machine in vmware. i have installed LAMP server and i am trying to host a website from it. i have created a virtual host. my website is accessible in the host machine when i go to the address 192.168.0.106.

i have connected the internet through a wifi router. i don't have a static ip. when i go to my router info, i get this:

**LAN**

MAC Address :B0:C5:54:83:90:FA

IP Address :192.168.0.1

Subnet Mask :255.255.255.0

DHCP Server :Enabled

**INTERNET**

MAC Address :B0:C5:54:83:90:FB

IP Address :10.30.195.241

Subnet Mask :255.255.224.0

Default Gateway :10.30.192.1

DNS :113.193.5.23

113.193.12.14

when i search for "what is my ip" in google, i get this: 113.193.56.198, both in host and guest os.

now, my issue is that how do i access my site from the internet? i know that i will have to edit hosts file and virtual host config file in ubuntu, but which ip address do i have to use? do I need to set up a dns server? i have a domain registered in godaddy, i want to know which ip address should i put in "points to" in the domain setting page.

basically, i want to know which ip address should i type in address bar to go to my site, even if it works for only one day, and how do i edit the hosts file and configuration file in ubuntu to use that ip. i have tried searching in many forums and have not found the kind of clarity i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't

Long answer: The only way that I know is using a dynamic dns server, but AFAIK there is no free dynamic dns that will work with a custom domain name. And the solution is so cheese that paying for a fixed IP is much more reasonable.

Normal DNS will never work, as usually your IP will change faster than dns propagation.

In any case you will need to put your public IP (113.193.56.198 now) in a browser(1) to access your site and this is what you should put in "points to" in the domain page.

(1) To make this work in your LAN you will need to meddle with DNS settings and host files. You can try it from outside you LAN, usually the easiest way to test it is to disconnect your phone from your wifi (if it is connected) and try from it.

Comment: You may also need to forward the port 80 (for http) in the Wifi router to the local IP, probably 192.168.0.106, port 80. Then you may be able to access the web server from outside by typing the current WAN IP address: 113.193.56.198.

Comment: hi, i actually got it working!!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073835/how-do-i-make-my-website-accessible-to-the-internet-without-a-static-ip-and-from  

"usually the easiest way to test it is to disconnect your phone from your wifi (if it is connected) and try from it." i tried it and i was able to see my site, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Router WAN IP Address 10.30.195.241 means your provider NAT'ed you *(it's not legal in some countries to call such service "Internet access" by the way)*: supplied you internet access without global IP address through it's NAT router ( 10.30.195.241 - is local IP address not visible from Internet).

### Some possible ways

1. Pay your ISP for global (and preferbly static) IP address if available. Set up port forwarding at you router to VM's IP. Access your web-server with that global IP address.
2. Use VPN service with global (and preferbly static) IP to bypass providers NAT. Setup port forwarding at VPN service or, if unavailable, create VPN tunnel directly from VM. Access your web-server with that global IP address.
3. Set up IPv6 address, either at Windows host or Ubuntu guest, and use any [IPv6 transition mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanisms) to connect to IPv6 Internet. Eg. Windows has build-in Teredo tunneling for this. Access your web-server with that IPv6 address.

Also, you could add DNS record for easier access to IP address or use DNS name supplied by ISP/VPN service/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site: [freedns.afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org) it supports open DNS and can update custom domains. I use it for personal websites etc works a treat.

If you need any help setting it up if be more than happy to help :)